# Chrome console returning undefined when output is expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I wrote some code in chrome console to get all the functions on a webpage:

```
for(var b in window) { 
   if(typeof(b) == "function") console.log(b);}
```

however although there are functions on the webpage the only output i get is "undefined"

Comment: try using the '===' operator

Comment: @VincentChinner Makes no difference

Comment: This will give you only window methods, not “all the functions on a webpage”

Comment: `b` will loop on property not value. Use `typeof(window[b])` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`b` is the KEY of the window object, `window[b]` is the value. The key will always be a string.

```
for(var b in window) { 
   if(typeof(window[b]) == "function") console.log(b);}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var b in window) {
```

Here, you're iterating through *keys*, not properties of the object. `typeof` of those keys is `string`, hence the condition under the `if` will never be fulfilled. And the `undefined` you get printed in the console is the value of the `for` statement (which is undefined).

Do instead

```
for(var b in window) { 
   if(typeof(window[b]) == "function") console.log(window[b]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

b is the propery name (string), not the function itself. Try like this:

```
for(var b in window){
    if(typeof window[b]=='function') console.log(b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The b variable ever is the type string, change left side condition to obtain function of window.

```
typeof(b)         // return string
typeof(window[b]) // return function
```

So the answer is this:

```
for(var b in window) { 
    if(typeof(window[b]) === "function") 
    {
        console.log(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we consider your code, 'typeof(b) == "function" ' it will never check this condition because typeof(b) is always a string.

The basic syntax to get a "string" key is obj["stringFormatKey"]. So here is the solution.

```
for(var b in window) { 
if(typeof(window[b]) == "function") console.log(b);}
```